# Python: Why can't I access variables in an IF that I declared right before / at the start of the file?

Tags: python, variables, methods

I have a created a variable at the start of my program, and another in a def before an important IF. However, I keep running into problems with reading & writing them.

I have the following code snippet:

```
#(...)
move_to = "finishedImages"
amount_moved = 0

def put_in(is_training:bool, file:Path):
    pthstr = file.__str__()
    target = move_to
    if is_training:
        target = target + "/train" # Makes a local instead!
    else:
        target = target + "/test" # Makes a local instead!

    shutil.move(file, move_to )
    shutil.move(pthstr[:len(pthstr) - 3] + "jpg", move_to)
    amount_moved += 1 # Can't even read amount_moved!
#(...)
```

My problem is that the IF does not override the target variable but insted creates a new local one, despite the fact it can read it. In effect, these lines become useless as my program continues to use the old target value.

Furthermore, the amount_moved cannot be accessed.

I'm more used to other languages where the scope system is rather simple such as Java, help!

Comment: "_cannot be accessed_"?  You mean it simply does not get incremented, or that you get a runtime error?  Any diagnostics output should be included in the question.

Comment: Sorry, with that I meant to say it cannot be resolved

Comment: You can read global variables in your function, but when you do `amount_moved += 1` you define a new local variable. There is the `global` keyword, but changing a global variable in a function is a bad idea in over 99% of all cases where it is used (yes, this is one of thise cases). Use a different variable and return it at the end of the function.

Comment: Thank you! I just solved it using globals, but made a different solution according to your input.
Can I add my solution here? The question is closed so I can't respond, should I edit my question instead?

Comment: What would your solution add over anything already mentioned in the duplicate?

Comment: A nice solution to the problem that should be easy to understand for Python beginners like me. I couldn't really find any good examples. The duplicate's answer lacks the completed code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/370364/476…?!

Comment: Ah, I didn't see that. I still think it'd be nice to have full solutions with- and without globals, but if you deem it unnecessary then let's leave it at that. And thanks for the help again!